# Js количество одинаковых элементов в массиве js добавить его в console

Tags: javascript

Сейчас выводит количество повторяющих элементов (число 3). А нужно еще вывести и его [2, 2, 2]

```js
var arr = [2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1];
var q = 1;
var e = -1;
var max = -1;
var pos = -1;
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
  if (arr[i] == arr[i + 1]) {
    q++;
    if (max < q) {
      max = q;
      pos = i;
      e = arr[i];
    }
  } else {
    q = 1;
  }
}
console.log(max);
```

Comment: похоже, что текст вопроса - плохой машинный перевод

Comment: изменил  вопрос некорректный

Comment: Что именно должно быть выведено? Можете привести пример правильного результата?

Comment: должно его самого [2, 2, 2], а сейчас оно выводит его количество  т.е. 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var arr = [2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1];
var q = 1;
var e = -1;
var max = -1;
var pos = -1;
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
  if (arr[i] == arr[i + 1]) {
    q++;
    if (max < q) {
      max = q;
      pos = i;
      e = arr[i];
    }
  } else {
    q = 1;
  }
}
console.log(max);
console.log(Array(max).fill(e));
```

Comment: Интересно вы вывели массив. Креативно =)

Comment: я про это тоже думал так , спасибо) а может есть у кого ссылка на альтернативный пример решения этой задачи

Comment: @Telion https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill#Examples